# Slider Load issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am using the Pointelle Slider (http://slidervilla.com/pointelle/) on my website http://mensdepression.org and everything is fine except that when the page loads all of the slides show, blink and then are hidden, but the user sees this as not a smooth experience. How can I improve the slider loading on page load so it is smoother?

Im using w3 total cache and I have a fast Liquid Web SSD VPN server. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in "header.php" just before tag:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');

wp_head();
```

Comment: superb. you are my hero @Engr Zardari :D i had the same issue, got it working perfectly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in "header.php" just before  tag:

```
wp_head();
```

Use this code in "footer.php" just before  tag:

```
wp_footer();
```

Comment: Disable all plugins for the time being. and check your slider is running or not. Most probably cause about slider not running is colliding more than one javascript.